# React cannot index into array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am trying to index into the array, but it seems that React thinks I am using object bracket notation.

In the console indexing into the array works as expected:

[image]

But React thinks this is a property of undefined:

[image]

Obj is definitely defined, so is otherChoices, so this error doesn't make sense to me.
If I comment out line 12 (or remove the index), then it runs and I see obj in my props:

[image]

This is a functional component:

```
 const ChoiceList = ({...obj}, isCorrect) => {

const  answer = obj.answer;
//console.log(obj)
// const  choice3 = obj.
const choice4 = obj.otherChoices[0];
const {choice1, choice2} = "Temp Vals"

const Arr = [{choice: answer, isAnswer: true },
                {choice: choice1, isAnswer: false},
                {choice: choice2, isAnswer: false}
                 ];

const scrambledArr = utils.shuffle(Arr)

    return (
        <div className="ChoiceList row">
            {scrambledArr.map(c => (
                <Choice choice={c.choice} isAnswer={c.isAnswer} isCorrect={isCorrect} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

 export default ChoiceList
```

Is there another way to index into an array?

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: try this `const choice4 = otherChoices[0];`

Comment: Then it says otherChoices is undefined (which makes sense).

Comment: If you console.log Object.keys(obj) does 'otherChoices' appear as one of the keys? If you do Object.values(obj) do the values show up accordingly?

Comment: can you try const `choice4 = obj.otherChoices && obj.otherChoices[0];`

Comment: @rrd -- It does not, obj shows up! That solves it for me :)  Maybe it has something to do with the spread operator, I need to deepen my knowledge of it

Comment: @AncientElevator9 FYI: your component may not receive all the props at 1st render, that is why your object from props might be empty or, most commonly, undefined (depends on logic at upper level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With rrd's comment I found the solution, but still don't know why, I'll have to do some experimenting

For some reason the obj was nested like this

```
{
"obj:"
    {
     "obj": {
         "answer": "",
         "otherChoices": ["", ""]},
     "isCorrect": Object
     }
 }
```

I removed the spread operator and the object isn't nested like this. I need to keep the curly brackets.

Comment: Maybe instead of  ({...obj}, isCorrect)   it should be (...obj, isCorrect)